# C++ Do-while loop doesn't work as i expected

Tags: c++, do-while

```cpp
int main()
{
    int a; //virknes skaitlis
    int N; //skaitlis
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    double average;
    int ok;

    do {
        cout << "Ievadiet, cik skaitļu būs virknē: " << endl;
        cin >> a;
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            cout << "Ievadiet veselu skaitli: " << endl;
            cin >> N;
            if (N % 2 == 1) {
                count++;
                sum += N;
            }
        }
        average = (double)sum / count;
        cout << "Virknes nepāra skaitļu vidējā artimētiskā vērtība ir: " << average << endl;
        cout << " Vai turpināt (1) vai beigt (0)?" << endl;
        cin >> ok;
    } while (ok == 1);

    if (sum == 0) {
        cout << "Nevar aprēķināt nepāra skaitļu vidējo aritmētisko." << endl;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

This program should ask to type how many numbers will be in chain and then calculate the existing between these numbers the arithmetic mean of the odd numbers. It is working, but the problem is in the second loop. On the second loop the arithmetic mean is already incorrect because program includes numbers FROM THE FIRST LOOP too, but I need to make them independent. What should I do to make loops independent so I could run several loops without exiting the programm.

Comment: declare varaibles only when you need them. Chances are high that this alone will fix your problem

Comment: Move the definition of the `N`, `count` and `a` variables to be inside the loop?

Comment: In addition to what idclev recommended, try indenting your code consistently. That will help you to see the structural problem which idclev is implying. (Ha, I see that somebody just did. But you really should embrace the idea why this is useful.)

Comment: @Yunnosch Could you please show how to move variables into the loop. im doing something wrong and it's doesn't work.

Comment: `do { int count = 0; ...`

Comment: Please show the code for "im doing something wrong", as an [edit] to the question, showing code introduced as "based on comments I tried to modify like this: ..... But it misbehaves by doing ... instead of the expected ...". I.e. please make a [mre] of the problem. As long as there is no answer which you invalidate you can change your question to be more to the point.

Comment: It fails on negative numbers! https://godbolt.org/z/T9zP9d

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe my amendments to your code would smooth things out:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a; //virknes skaitlis
    int N; //skaitlis
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    double average;
    int ok;

    do {
        count = 0;
        sum = 0;
        cout << endl << endl << "Ievadiet, cik skaitļu būs virknē: ";
        cin >> a;
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            cout << "Ievadiet veselu skaitli: ";
            cin >> N;
            if (N % 2 == 1) {
                count++;
                sum += N;
            }
        }
        if (count != 0) { 
            average = (double)sum / count;
            cout << endl << "Virknes nepāra skaitļu vidējā artimētiskā vērtība ir: " << average << endl;
        } else { 
            cout << endl << "Nevar aprēķināt nepāra skaitļu vidējo aritmētisko.\nNetika ievadīti nepāra skaitļi." << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << "Vai turpināt (1) vai beigt (0)? :  ";
        cin >> ok;
    } while (ok == 1);

    cout << endl;

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: But it's hard to see what has actually changed. A good answer should not just provide the fixed code, but focus on explaining the problem, so OP will learn _what_ was wrong and _how_ to fix it instead of just copy-pasting code. So maybe you want to add some explanations here.

Comment: Oh didn't know that, sorry!  
  
So, the changes are:  
  
1. The variables '**count**' and '**sum**' have been redefined within the '_do_' loop. However, you may simply declare those two variables within the loop and discard their global declarations, as the variables are only operated on within the '_do_' loop.  
  
2. The '**average**' variable is defined (or functioned) only if the '**count**' variable is not a zero (0) value. This is to avoid a division by 0, thereby avoiding a possible run-time error. Hence, the '_if-else_' conditional statement.  . . .

Comment: 3. The erstwhile error message (at the end of your original code) with respect to the '_if ( sum == 0 )_' statement has been incorporated within the '_else_' conditional statement for reasons mentioned in the second element of this list. This made the original error message redundant.

4. A few additional **endl**'s have been added here and there for a better visual presentation (on output).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double sum;
    for(;;)
    {
        int amount = 0;
        sum = 0;
        int a;

        std::cout << "Ievadiet, cik skaitļu būs virknē: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> a;

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "Ievadiet veselu skaitli: " << std::endl;
            int N;
            std::cin >> N;
            if (N % 2 == 1)
            {
                amount++;
                sum += N;
            }
        }
        double average = (double)sum / amount;
        std::cout << "Virknes nepāra skaitļu vidējā artimētiskā vērtība ir: " << average << std::endl;
        std::cout << " Vai turpināt (1) vai beigt (0)?" << std::endl;
        int ok;
        std::cin >> ok;

        if (ok != 1){
            break;
        }
    }

    if (sum == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Nevar aprēķināt nepāra skaitļu vidējo aritmētisko." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this works.

It's important to think about the scope of your variables if I were to do this

```
int p = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    p++;
}
//here p would still be 100, because it was declared outside of the scope of the for loop
```

If I were to do this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    int p = 0;
    p++;
    //would never get bigger then 1, because every iteration it gets reinstantiated.
}
//here p would be non-existent outside of the scope.
```

Every time you leave a scope (pretty much anything with curly brackets), the stack allocated variables in that scope would just be deleted.

Heap allocated variables to not automatically go away, you have to explicitly delete it.

```
//heap allocated variable, recognised by the new keyword, which returns a pointer to your new variable.
int *numbers = new int[100];

//to delete it. If you don't do this you would get a memory leak.
delete numbers;
```

Comment: But it's hard to see _why_ this works, or why you hope it should. A good answer should not just provide the fixed code, but focus on explaining the problem, so OP will learn _what_ was wrong and _how_ to fix it instead of just copy-pasting code. So maybe you want to add some explanations here.